# What is the expected behavior of CopyTo in the context of an IDictionary?

Tags: .net, collections, interface, dictionary

I'm looking at the interface `IDictionary<T, U>`. One weird thing I noted in the list of methods that must be implemented is `CopyTo` with the description:

> Copies the elements of the ICollection to an Array, starting at a
>   particular Array index.

What does this even mean in the context of a dictionary? Does this mean copy the values to the array or the keys or KeyValuePairs or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`  and the `CopyTo` method's type the generic parameter for the `ICollection<T>` interface it will return an array of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects.